# How to pass parameters in windows service from Installer to Main function in Program.cs?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have successfully passed parameters from Installutil to my serviceinstaller but i cannt seem to pass these parameters to the Main(string[ args] function.
Here is how i am trying to do this ....if there is any better wayto do what i am doing please let me know

```
    protected override void OnAfterInstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.OnAfterInstall(savedState);
        string[] args = new string[2];
        args[0] = Context.Parameters["username"];
        args[0] = Context.Parameters["password"];
        new ServiceController(this.dataLoaderServiceInstaller.ServiceName).Start(args);
    }
```

and this is my Program.cs

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create a writer and open the file
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\\bw\\date.txt");

        // write a line of text to the file
        tw.WriteLine(args.Length);

        // close the stream
        tw.Close();
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
      new DataloaderService() 
    };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
```

the length of arugments that i am trying to write is always zero.
One more question will these parameters still exist after the computer/server restarts for maintenance?
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters you send using ServiceController.Start() method are available to you as parameters to the OnStart() method. If I'm not mistaken (It's been a while since I needed to do this).

The OnStart method's signature is:

```
OnStart(string[] args)
```

However, if you need the parameters to be sent to the service each time the service is started (automatically) on boot, then you should look at the MSDN documentation on this. Specifically

> Process initialization arguments for
>   the service in the OnStart method, not
>   in the Main method. The arguments in
>   the args parameter array can be set
>   manually in the properties window for
>   the service in the Services console.
>   The arguments entered in the console
>   are not saved; they are passed to the
>   service on a one-time basis when the
>   service is started from the control
>   panel. Arguments that must be present
>   when the service is automatically
>   started can be placed in the ImagePath
>   string value for the service's
>   registry key
>   (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\). You can obtain the arguments
>   from the registry using the
>   GetCommandLineArgs method, for
>   example: string[] imagePathArgs =
>   Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx

Comment: thanks Kumar :) what would be best way to store a password ...ImagePath doesn't look like the best way to store a password

Comment: I don't believe services should need passwords and such. If you need the service to run as a specific user then that can be set up after install. So maybe a rethinking of your design is in order

Comment: my service access email account for some processing so i need to store password for my email account

Comment: Then use the registry as described in the MSDN documentation. You could also use a file (like a config file) that is in a known location that contains the information. In either case the password can be encrypted if you're concerned about that.

Comment: the msdn documentation on the imagepath is a little hazy. can you provide a sample that does it?